# oracle join one to many relationship, return 1st joining date

Tags: sql, oracle, join, one-to-many

I am trying to join two tables whereby one person can have more than one card and some of them might be canceled.

For example :

```
**Customer Card**
Cust ID | Cust Acct | Card No | Join Date | Cancel Date
1       | 10001     | E100001 | 20150501  | 20160101
1       | 10001     | E100002 | 20151001  | 0
2       | 10002     | E100003 | 20150101  | 20160601
3       | 10003     | E100004 | 20150201  | 0
4       | 10003     | E100005 | 20160101  | 0 

**Customer Account**
Cust ID | Cust Acct 
1       | 10001     
2       | 10002     
3       | 10003
```

Basically, I want to show all accounts with 1st join card no, even though card is canceled. If the 1st card is canceled, then needs to show the 2nd card joining date.

The expected result :

```
Cust ID | Cust Acct | Card No | Join Date | Cancel Date
1       | 10001     | E100002 | 20151001  | 0
2       | 10002     | E100003 | 20151001  | 20160601
3       | 10003     | E100004 | 20150201  | 0
```

Thanks for the assistance ! Any idea ?

Comment: What if all cards are cancelled for a customer, in that case what should be displayed?

Comment: Display the earliest joining

Answer (score 1):

One method uses `row_number()`:

```
select cc.*, ca.CardNo, ca.JoinDate, ca.CancelDate
from customercard cc join
     (select ca.*, 
             row_number() over (partition by custid order by joindate asc) as seqnum
      from customeraccount ca
     ) ca
     on cc.custid = ca.custid and seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Sorry, i edited my question. I missed out one condition. If the 1st card is canceled, then needs to show the 2nd card joining date instead of 1st card joining date.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in one pass over the data (without requiring a subquery and outer query), using `GROUP BY` and `KEEP(DENSE_RANK FIRST)`.

First some housekeeping.

- Table and column names cannot have spaces in them (unless you use double-quoted names, which is an unnecessary and very poor practice in most cases).
- Your date columns seem to be in number format, which is a very poor practice. How can you prevent an input like 20151490 (the 90-th day of the 14-th month) being stored in the db? All dates SHOULD be stored as dates. However, storing them in exactly that format allows correct order comparison (although that is just by accident and shouldn't be relied on). Since that is not the main point of your question, though, I used the data as is.
- Why do you need a join? The first table should not include the `cust_id` - including it violates the second normal form of database design. If you do, in fact, have that column in the first table, I don't see the need for the second table, or for a join. (If the `cust_id` is not in the first table, then you do need a join, but I will leave that aside since the question is really about picking the right rows, not about joining - despite the title).
- In the first table you have two `cust_id`, 3 and 4, associated with the same account (and contradicting the second table, too). I assume that's a typo and in fact 4 should be 3 - but this illustrates EXACTLY why second normal form is so important. You SHOULD NOT have `cust_id` in the first table.

The key to your reformulated requirement is conditional ordering. If for a given account all cards on file are canceled, or if none is canceled, then pick the one with the earliest `join_date`. However, if an account has a mix of both kinds of cards, then pick the earliest card that is not canceled. In SQL, that can be achieved with a composite ordering (by two expressions, of which the SECOND is `join_date`). The first criterion is the "conditional" part. In the solution below, I use the expression `CASE when cancel_date = 0 then 0 end`. That is, a card that has NOT been canceled will have a flag of 0, and one that is canceled will have the flag `NULL` (the default if there is no `ELSE` part in the `CASE` expression). By default, `NULL` comes last in an ordering (which is `asc`ending by default). So, if all cards are still valid they will all have the flag 0 and the ordering by this flag won't matter. If all are canceled the flag is NULL for all, so ordering by this flag won't matter. But if some are valid and some canceled, then the valid ones will come first, so the earliest date will be picked only from valid cards.

Note that `then 0` (the flag value of 0) is irrelevant; I could make it 1, or even a string (`then 'a'`) and the "conditional ordering" would work just the same, and for the same reason. I attach something that is not `NULL` to valid cards and `NULL` to canceled cards; that's all that matters.

This is the change that Gordon would need to make his solution work, too. But, in cases like this, I prefer the `KEEP(DENSE_RANK FIRST)` approach, especially if performance is important (as might be the case when you have a very large number of customers, accounts, and credit cards on file).

```
with
     customer_card ( cust_id , cust_acct , card_no , join_date , cancel_date ) as (
       select 1, 10001, 'E100001', 20150501, 20160101 from dual union all
       select 1, 10001, 'E100002', 20151001,        0 from dual union all
       select 2, 10002, 'E100003', 20150101, 20160601 from dual union all
       select 3, 10003, 'E100004', 20150201,        0 from dual union all
       select 3, 10003, 'E100005', 20160101,        0 from dual
     )
-- end of test data; actual solution begins HERE
select cust_id, cust_acct,
       min(card_no) keep (dense_rank first
             order by case when cancel_date = 0 then 0 end, join_date) as card_no,
       min(join_date) keep (dense_rank first
             order by case when cancel_date = 0 then 0 end, join_date) as join_date,
       min(cancel_date) keep (dense_rank first
             order by case when cancel_date = 0 then 0 end, join_date) as cancel_date
from   customer_card
group by cust_id, cust_acct
order by cust_id, cust_acct   --  ORDER BY is optional
;
```

**Output**:

```
  CUST_ID  CUST_ACCT CARD_NO JOIN_DATE CANCEL_DATE
--------- ---------- ------- --------- -----------
        1      10001 E100002  20151001           0
        2      10002 E100003  20150101    20160601
        3      10003 E100004  20150201           0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Edit:  I'm stealing mathguy's "customer_card" table creation.  Would imagine his way works too, so here's another solution:

```
with
     customer_card ( cust_id , cust_acct , card_no , join_date , cancel_date ) as (
       select 1, 10001, 'E100001', 20150501, 20160101 from dual union all
       select 1, 10001, 'E100002', 20151001,        0 from dual union all
       select 2, 10002, 'E100003', 20150101, 20160601 from dual union all
       select 3, 10003, 'E100004', 20150201,        0 from dual union all
       select 3, 10003, 'E100005', 20160101,        0 from dual
     )
, allresults as(
select
cust_id,
cust_acct,
card_no,
join_date,
cancel_date,
rank() over(partition by cust_acct order by decode(cancel_date, 0, 1, 2), join_date, rownum) DATE_RANK

from customer_card
)

select
*
from allresults
where DATE_RANK = 1
```

Comment: "Stealing" the table (rather, test data subquery) creation is absolutely fine, I do it myself whenever I can. {:-)

Comment: Thanks. Just couldn't do it without giving you the credit :)